# How to build Islam in Fantasy?

Tags: religion

I'm a novice writer and I'm writing a novel, or trying to,  where there is a magic world and a science world.  So, I'm starting on the magic world with Xianxia , Xuanhuan and other things that are kind of magical like Ki, Qi, Chakra etc. and also mixing other sub genera of fantasy. The novel is  kinda like this. There is a magic universe that science can't fully understand or there aren't any resource with which science can advance. My male protagonist gets the embodiment of death power with another power associated with it (like cold, decay or life?) and in this novel there would be a lot of kinds of mythological gods and creature and other races like elves, vampires, orcs, etc and without our current religions gods. The way my novel is that every magical Plane or dimension or world has home of different mythologies. But I don't know what to do with Islam. I don't know what to do with it including with Judaism and Christianity. So can anyone help with this complex religion or I should exclude them in the novel and make new god based off them.

Comment: My advice: **don't**. First: why would you need to? Second: are you really sure you can do it without seeming caricatural, heretic etc? Unless, of course, that's what you want.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? How the religion would develop given these conditions, how it would react, how it would continue to exist?

Comment: I think i can make other religions like Hindu,Buddhisms and other mythological gods co exist with each other or just fight between gods or stay neutral state but those three man there are pain in the ass.

Comment: If you are novice writer, _stay away_ from dangerous topics like religion, rape, child abuse, etc. It is _really, really easy_ to piss off a lot of people if you get a few things wrong, and more often than not you _will_ get things wrong if you're not experienced enough.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Zombie Slayer. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to specific questions. If you would [edit] your question to indicate the exact problem you're having, the community would appreciate it. As is, your question lacks clarity in what you want from the WB SE. (Also, you can ping one user per comment using the @<username> syntax.)

Comment: Hello can i asked things about powers or something.

Comment: Ours grand-grand-grand...(you got it) parents believed magic was real. If you read the Coran (I suggest it, as well the Bible and other religious texts) you find plenty of magic. Bad thing occidental European almost banned magic as a demoniac thing but it's present. In Apocrypha, you can even find Christ dueling with a mage. So magic is not, in any way, incompatible with Judaic (or any)religion or any of its branches. To spread it in your world you can just summon a few muslins from our world

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at the novel *Small Gods*, by Terry Pratchett. It takes a satirical look at such a situation, where one religion believes that only their god is real, and that all other gods are either fictional or demonic.

Islam in the real world has similar features, particularly in the form of *Jinn*. Jinn are sentient creatures who can be good, evil, or neutral. An Islam-analogue in a world that actually *does* contain gods might explain those other gods as being Jinn that have tricked humans into worshipping them.

Another approach might be that used by J.R.R. Tolkien. In the Tolkien legendarium, there is a creator deity named Eru or Illuvatar. This deity then created powerful spirits to be with him in the void; after the creation of the physical world, some of those spirits entered the world to build it and manage it on behalf of Eru. These were the Valar. The Silmarillion explicitly states that Men have often worshipped the Valar as gods - indeed, they were specifically created to be equivalent to the gods of European polytheism. Your world could have a similar belief system, whether well-founded or not, that believes that there is an overarching creative force, and that the other gods of the world are just this force's agents.